# Regex to convert usernames within text to links to their profile

Tags: php, regex

Using this regex, I can find all usernames within the body of my comments and change them into hyperlinks:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\B\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/', '<a href="/profiles/$1">$0</a>', $row["commentBody"]);
```

This will convert `@user` to `<a href="/profiles/user">@user</a>` (broken  link obviously).

However it will also convert `h@user` to `h<a href="/profiles/user">@user</a>` which I don't want.

How can I modify the regex to only change the string if their is two spaces either side of it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your pattern. This will not convert a substring like `h@user`. The `\B` forbid this. However adding a lookahead at the end, as Ωmega do, is a good idea : `(?!\w)` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** missed the two spaces thing before and fixed to limit to 16 characters:

```
$body = preg_replace('/(?<=^|  )\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,16})(?:  )/', '<a href="/profiles/$1">$0</a>', $row["commentBody"]);
```

(end edit)

Better is this:

```
$body = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s|[([])\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/', '<a href="/profiles/$1">$0</a>', $row["commentBody"]);
```

I suspect the current problem is that you have a hidden character or something in there.  For example, look what happens if you do this:

```
$body = 'h<!-- comment -->@user'; // or even something like '<strong>h</strong>@user'
$body = preg_replace('/\B\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/', '<a href="/profiles/$1">$0</a>', $body);
echo htmlentities($body);
```

You aren't feeding it `h@user`, even though it looks like it, which explains why you are getting the output you are describing.

Also, you say it will convert `$user`.  It shouldn't; the way you have it written, it will match `@user`, but not `$user`.  If you want it to match both, replace `\@` with `[@$]`.

Comment: How can I change \b to mean if nothing is before it? Because is the @user is at the beggining of the string it is not changed to a link

Comment: Try my suggestion under "Better is this:" -- it works at the beginning of the string due to the `^`.

Comment: Grrr... http://ideone.com/LLEeX2

Comment: @Ωmega -- this is because of the `{1,20}` limitation.  If he wants it to match more characters, he could just do `+\b` where the `{1,20}` is now.

Comment: Nope. Read OP's question again - it says `..if their is two spaces either side of it...`

Comment: @EdCottrell that's not nessecary as usernames can only be 16 characters long

Comment: @e_e Sir, stackoverflow is here for all users, not just you, so you better clarify your question, so it will be useful not just for you and only!

Comment: @Ωmega Good point, thanks.

Comment: @EdCottrell, the edit at the top of your question doesn't work. However the better is this version does

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|(?<=\s))\@(\w{1,20})(?!\w)/', '<a href="/profiles/$1">$0</a>', ...
```

or

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|(?<=\s))\@(\w{1,20})(?=\s|$)/', ...
```